# Istio on Kubernetes - Version compatibility mapping

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Is there a link that shows the mapping of Istio and supported Kubernetes? The FAQ section just mentions this... "For our 1.0 release, Istio supports environments running container orchestration platforms such as Kubernetes (v1.9 or greater) and Nomad (with Consul).". What about the releases after 1.0?

Comment: I think the current stable relelase is 1.0 only and thatst , they will update the documentation when there are other major versions

Answer (score 2):

1.0 is the current release.

The documentation for the upcoming next release (1.1) is available from the options and settings menu (gear icon) in the top right corner of the istio.io site.

On the kubernetes setup page it says that it's been tested on Kubernetes 1.10, 1.11, and 1.12. https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/quick-start/